# Class based view and call function to script

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I'm learning django and I'm facing a problem I can't figure how to debug.

I have a lobby_detail.html template that shows a button like this:

```
<button type="button" href="{% url 'sign'%}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Sign this Document</button>
```

The template is a Detail view modelview:

```
class LobbyDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Lobby
```

I would like the button to execute some code that requires both user connected and current lobby instances

How can I use the button thanks to class based view?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `dispatch()` method in your view. `get()` and `post()` methods are also available.

```
class LobbyDetailViewButton(generic.DetailView):
    # this should be where the button url connects
    model = Lobby

    # use dispatch for your code
    def dispatch(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        lobby_object = self.get_object()
        user_object = request.user
        # do stuff with lobby_object & user_object
        return super().dispatch(request,*args, **kwargs) 
        # can also return an http request
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, how does dispatch work? I'm trying to understand the thing.

Comment: The documentation, which is good, is probably better at explaining it then I am: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch

But also make sure you're clear on how methods in python objects work  – `def(dispatch)` is a method of the object `LobbyDetailViewButton`